# How to check if the double or float value has only one decimal place in Java

Tags: java

For eg. there is a float value 1345.1, then how do I check whether it has only one decimal place and not more than that?

Comment: is this a String representation of a float?  Otherwise the value may not be exactly what you think it is anyway.  If this is a String then just test the length after the dot.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Good point, I can do that. This is the String representation, so I can test the length after the dot. Thanks, this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically you cannot have a float number as precise as this, it always has more digits unless someone already rounded it for you. Is it the case? If that's the case I think you could parse it as a String and count the digits after the dot.
I would do it like this:

```
float floatNumber = 24.04;
String floatAsString= String.valueOf(floatNumber);
int indexOfDecimal = floatAsString.indexOf(".");
if(floatAsString.substring(indexOfDecimal).length == 1) {return true;}
```

Comment: you can use `if(floatAsString.length() - indexOfDecimal + 1 == 1)`

Comment: How would it work with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken ?